Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
const cron = require('node-cron')
const { Op } = require('sequelize')
const EmployeeDocumentsService = require('@/services/employee/EmployeeDocumentsService')
const EmailService = require('@/services/email/EmailService') // Your email service
const { MODEL_EMPLOYEEDOCUMENTS } = require('@/constants/modelName')

// Assuming you have a way to access your database connection
const conn = require('@/models') // Adjust this according to your project structure

const notifyExpiredDocuments = async () => {
    const today = new Date()
    const expirationDate = new Date()
    expirationDate.setDate(today.getDate() + 15) // Set to 15 days from today

    const documents = await conn[MODEL_EMPLOYEEDOCUMENTS].findAll({
        where: {
            validUntil: {
                [Op.lte]: expirationDate,
                [Op.gt]: today,
            },
        },
        include: [
            {
                association: 'Employee', // Assuming you have an employee model
                attributes: ['officialEmail', 'firstName'], // Include employee's email and name
            },
        ],
    })

    for (const document of documents) {
        const employeeEmail = document.Employee.officialEmail
        const employeeName = document.Employee.firstName
        const subject = `Document Expiration Reminder for ${document.documentName}`
        const templateData = {
            name: employeeName,
            documentName: document.documentName,
            validUntil: document.validUntil.toDateString(),
        }

        try {
            await EmailService().sendMail(
                'DOC_EXPIRY',
                employeeEmail,
                employeeName,
                templateData
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending email:', error)
        }
    }
}
notifyExpiredDocuments().catch(console.error)
// Schedule the cron job to run daily at 9 AM
cron.schedule('0 9 * * *', () => {
    console.log('Checking for expiring documents...')
    notifyExpiredDocuments().catch(console.error)
})


here i need to set cronjob for document expiry email triggering but it shows this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
    at notifyExpiredDocuments (C:\Users\Md-Azath\Desktop\hris\backend\src\jobs\cronjob.js:15:59)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Md-Azath\Desktop\hris\backend\src\jobs\cronjob.js:52:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Md-Azath\Desktop\hris\backend\src\app.js:19:1)

i need the correct function

The error appears to be indicating that conn[MODEL_EMPLOYEEDOCUMENTS] is undefined.  What value do you expect it to have and why?  What value does MODEL_EMPLOYEEDOCUMENTS have when the error occurs?  What value does conn have when the error occurs?  How do either of these differ from what you expect?
